# How to merge monthly datasets side by side?

Tags: r, merge, dataset

I have monthly datasets excel files. And I want to combine those files into one. I wanted to see the movement of payments of my customer monthly side by side (see sample table)

| customer | January | February |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 800 |
| 2 | 2000 | 1800 |

But I do not know how to make it like that. Please help me, thank you so much.

I tried to merge the monthly datasets but the output is literally merge, like this,

| customer | payment | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | January |
| 1 | 800. | February |

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% pivot_longer(-c(customer),names_to = 'month', values_to = 'payments')

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  customer month    payments
     <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
1        1 January      1000
2        1 February      800
3        2 January      2000
4        2 February     1800
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion without using any extra package.

```
df=data.frame(customer=c(1,2), January=c(1000,2000), February=c(800,1800))

ans.df=reshape(df, 
        direction = "long",
        varying = list(names(df)[2:3]),
        v.names = "Payment",
        idvar = c("Customer"),
        timevar = "Month",
        times = c('January','February'))

print(ans.df[, c('Customer','Payment','Month')])
```